# How to create a single function with different criteria on WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm newbie in PHP, so be kind please! And I'm sorry if it's too repeated, but my brain is burning. I want to learn how to change the variables using only one function of WordPress.

This is my variables...

```
function be_comu() {
$name = 'BE';
echo $name;
}

function cn_comu() {
$name = 'CN';
echo $name;
}

function mn_comu() {
$name = 'MN';
echo $name;
}
```

This is my function and `be_comu()` is a variable that I want to change.

```
function turismo() {
ob_start();
be_comu();
$rota = ob_get_clean();

echo $rota;
}
```

How to change the result to `cn_comu` or `mn_comu` without creating a new function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) (PHP is awesome that way):

```
function turismo($func_name) {
    // First, let's be sure the function actually exists to prevent fatal errors
    if ( ! function_exists($func_name) ) {
        echo "Whoah! Can't call a function that doesn't exist!";
        return;
    }

    // While output buffering is cool, doesn't have any value here...
    ob_start();
    // use call_user_func to call the function name we passed in...
    call_user_func($func_name);
    $rota = ob_get_clean();

    echo $rota;
}

// Results:
turismo('be_comu');
// outputs "BE"

turismo('cn_comu');
// outputs "NE"

turismo('non_existent_function');
// Outputs "Whoah! Can't call a function that doesn't exist!"
```

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I was looking for! Helped me a lot.